# Automated UI Tests for Cross Platform Phonegap app?

Tags: testing, cordova, tdd, automated-tests, bdd

I have a Phonegap app that run on Android, iOS and BlackBerry. I would like to write automated UI tests that can be run against the apps for each of the platforms. For example, I would want to implement tests such as "Given I am on the Search Results screen, When I press the Back button, Then I should see the Search screen" in something like Java only once and have these tests applied to each platform. What tools can I use for this?

I see I can use Selenium for testing websites on mobile platforms (and implement all these tests once in the same language) but I don't know how I can get Selenium to interact with the web view my app is contained within. Any tips?